# Highstock limit max zoom out

Tags: highcharts

I am using the highstock component to display stock history data that goes in the range of years. So what I require (if possible) is to set a max zoom range (the opposite of what minRange does) to limit the user to zoom out over several years...say to limit the zoom range to a maximum of one year.

Thanks in advance for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't any specific option for that. However, you can achieve that by using afterSetExtremes callback. In that callback you can compare event.min and event.max and set new extremes if timespan is bigger then your max.